# access denied for user @ 'localhost' to database ''

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp

I'm seeing a lot of of similar questions to this. but can't find one exactly like mine yet. Not sure where to change these settings or anything, any help appreciated.

```
access denied Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database ''
```

This is the beginning of my page.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost'; //unlikely to require changing.
$dbname ='publication'; //modify these
$dbuser = 'username'; //variables 
$dbpass = ''; //// to your installation
$appname = 'application name'; // and preference

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please also show the `mysql_connect` code.

Comment: Does your database have a password?  Either way it's showing that your username isn't being sent.

Comment: Can you connect to it through command line using the same credentials from the same host as where your script is running from?

Comment: phpAdmin ended up being what i needed.

Comment: If this is a test box, then you can use something like the following to get you going: `mysql -e GRANT ALL ON *.* TO ''@'localhost'`

Comment: set your $dbuser  to 'root'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this: [Adding users to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-accounts.html)

You need grant privileges to the user if you want external acess to database(ie. web pages).

Comment: i ended up using phpMyadmin, but yeah this is basically what i needed.

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely not using the correct credentials for the MySQL server.  You also need to ensure the user you are connecting as has the correct privileges to view databases/tables, and that you can connect from your current location in network topographic terms (localhost).

Comment: how do i change these things?

Comment: You have to use the credentials that you used when setting up MySQL for one, for the other things, Google is your best friend.. :)  I recommend using the user 'root' if possible.  It has all the rights necessary to do anything.  That would narrow down your inquiry to just being able to connect, and using the right credentials.