# Zend error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I am having trouble with zend framework and connection with database, I'm trying to create a login, the table is created, and the code apparently is fine, but gives me this:

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'onetag51_teste'@'localhost' (using  password: YES)
Stack trace:

#0 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(109):   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(860): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(930): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote('pass1', NULL)
#3 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Auth\Adapter\DbTable.php(449): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quoteInto('`password` = ?', 'pass1')
#4 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Auth\Adapter\DbTable.php(368): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->_authenticateCreateSelect()
#5 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Auth.php(117): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->authenticate()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Eulen\application\controllers\AuthenticationController.php(27): Zend_Auth->authenticate(Object(Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable))
#7 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): AuthenticationController->logininAction()
#8 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('logininAction')
#9 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#10 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#11 C:\xampp\Zend\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Eulen\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#13 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
'controller' => 'authentication',
'action' => 'loginin',
'module' => 'default',
 )
```

I was searching for a solution, and some of the possible errors were, spelling errors(I didn't find any), can't connect to phpmyadmin using my pass and user(if I go to the phpmyadmim site, I can enter using the username and password).

I have try several solution but I cant figure it out.

Am I missing something.

file config.ini:

```
 resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
 resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = "onetag51_teste"
resources.db.params.password = "*******"
resources.db.params.dbname = "onetag51_eulenhugo"
```

Its better to put here the authenticationcontroller, maybe the problem is there..

```
 <?php

 class AuthenticationController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

 public function init()
 {
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
}

public function logininAction()
{
    // action body
    $authAdapter =$this->getAuthAdapter();
    $username='hugo';
    $password='pass1';

    $authAdapter->setIdentity($username)
                ->setCredential($password);

    $auth =Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);
    if($result->isValid())
    {
        echo 'valid';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'invalid';
    }
}

public function logoutAction()
{
    // action body
}
private function  getAuthAdapter()
{
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());
    $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
                ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password');

    return $authAdapter;
}              


}
```

ive been talking to a friend of mine, and he told me that i need to set the permission for acesse the phpmyadmim through zend...

How can i do that?

Comment: just to be certain, "*******" is the actual parameter you have in you config.ini for password ? or you're using it just for the question, even if so I would suggest to change it to something random.

Comment: no, im using a my password, but ive switched for ****.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use quotations around your adpater, username, password and dbname in your config file.  I don't in mine, hope this helps.

I found a bit more reading that might be helpful [access denied for user @ 'localhost' to database ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621649/access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database) because it mentions

> You need grant privileges to the user if you want external acess to database(ie. web pages).
>    in the answer.

[There is also this link about adding the users to the database in mysql.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: i ve been looking in the link that you gave me, but the problem maintains.i have send a mail to the server telling them my problem, let me see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was related with the priveleges, thanks for ARJMP, ive tryed changed the priveleges but thee host didnd let me do it, so what i did was create a local database using xamp and try the login with the database that ive created in xamp, and it worked...