# How to grant super privilege to mysql database table in my website db

Tags: php, mysql

How to grant super privilege to my database to set global. How to grant super privilege? I got an error while granting the privilege .

```
Access Denied for the 'user'@'localhost'
```

Comment: It means the password you trying with was wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621649/access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database

Comment: I'd really, really be interested in why you want to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You should just execute these queries, make sure that MySQL user who executes these queries has GRANT and SUPER privilege:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_pass'; 

GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';
```